# apply_filters() slices away needed arguments

Tags: filters, hooks

I'm trying to add a button (its function is beyond the scope of this question, suffice it to say that it needs the refund id as an argument) to each refund line in a WooCommerce order. I found that those lines are created in woocommerce\includes\admin\meta-boxes\views\html-order-refund.php which can't be overridden. However there is an action:

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', null, $refund, $refund->get_id() );
```

This seemed perfect for my purpose, so I tried adding the following code to functions.php to test if it could work:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 'test_refund_id');
function test_refund_id($nullvar, $refund, $refund_id) {
    if ( !empty($refund->refunded_by) ){
        echo '<td>Refund ID: '.$refund_id.'</td>';  
    }
}
```

I used `if ( !empty($refund->refunded_by) )` because `woocommerce_admin_order_item_values` also gets called in html-order-shipping.php, html-order-item.php and html-order-fee.php, with an "order item" object (instead of a "refund" object) as the second argument, so there's no `refunded_by` property and my instruction should be ignored.

Much to my disappointment, though, I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to
>   function test_refund_id(), 1 passed in \wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php
>   on line 290 and exactly 3 expected in
>   \wp-content\themes\mytheme\functions.php:1087

I know that, as a matter of fact, three arguments are passed in the line I quoted above (namely a null, the refund object and the refund id), but I went and checked the script the error was referring to (\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php) around line 290, and I found this in the `apply_filters()` function:

```
        // Avoid the array_slice if possible.
        if ( $the_['accepted_args'] == 0 ) {
            $value = call_user_func( $the_['function'] );
        } elseif ( $the_['accepted_args'] >= $num_args ) {
            $value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], $args );
        } else {
            $value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], array_slice( $args, 0, (int) $the_['accepted_args'] ) );
        }
```

Just for testing purposes I tried to temporarily change the last "else" clause, replacing the "sliced" arguments array with the original one, thereby forcing the script to keep all the arguments anyway, so `array_slice( $args, 0, (int) $the_['accepted_args'] )` became simply `$args`. Surprise, surprise, now everything works smoothly!

[image]

Now, I'm well aware that's of course not a solution since I can't edit a core WP script. I would just want to understand WHY `apply_filters()` thinks that the accepted arguments are less than the passed ones and therefore it trims the argument array down to just the first one.

Thanks a lot in advance to anyone who'd like to shed some light on the matter.

Comment: You have to use add_action instead of add_filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two inherent problems with your script as posted. I'm not certain this will solve your problem, but it's too big to address in the comments.

First, you need to use `add_action()`, *not* `add_filter()`. That by itself is not a *huge* deal because `add_action()` is just a wrapper for `add_filter()`, but you should still use the correct one.

The other problem may be your passed arguments.

> I know that, as a matter of fact, three arguments are passed in the
>   line I quoted above (namely a null, the refund object and the refund
>   id),

Actually, the way you have it, you're not passing three arguments, you're only passing one. But your function as written is expecting three.

Your [`add_action()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) uses the required `$tag` and `$function_to_add` values, but leaves off the optional `$priority` and `$accepted_args`. The default of `$accepted_args` is "1", so anytime you're passing more than a single value with `add_action()` or `add_filter()`, you ***must*** define the `$accepted_args` value.

Try it as follows, noting the final value of "3" - that's the `$accepted_args` value that tells it to pass more than 1 argument:

```
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 'test_refund_id', 10, 3 );
function test_refund_id($nullvar, $refund, $refund_id) {
    if ( !empty($refund->refunded_by) ){
        echo '<td>Refund ID: '.$refund_id.'</td>';  
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working now! Didn't know about the $accepted_args parameter until today and I was so stupid not to check the codex for it.

Answer (score 5):

There's a fundamental misunderstanding here about how filters and actions work, here is the flaw in your thinking:

> I know that, as a matter of fact, three arguments are passed in

A closer inspection of `add_action` and `add_filter` reveals:

```php
add_action( string $tag, callable $function_to_add, int $priority = 10, int $accepted_args = 1 )
```

Notice the `$accepted_args` parameter. Because it isn't present in the call to `add_filter` in your question, it defaults to 1. To get 3 all parameters you need to specify 3. This is because not all filters need all parameters, and it can be useful to use other functions that can't accept all the parameters when only the first is needed. E.g. PHP internal math functions

Additional notes:

- you used `add_filter`, but it was an action that got called, `add_action` should be used for actions, and `add_filter` for filters
- 3rd party plugins are offtopic, the only reason your Q could be answered here is because it can be answered without knowledge of WooCommerce. The specifics about how that plugins internals work are not on topic here
- You need to add escaping to `$refund_id`, the lack of escaping is a security hole. `esc_html` should do the job
- Never modify WP Core internals, a quick look at the documentation almost always gives the answer

Comment: Totally missed the $accepted_args parameter so far. So silly of me, thanks for the clarification. As for your additional notes:

- I knew about WC being offtopic but as you said this had to do with WordPress itself;
- I also know about escaping, that was just quick testing code on a development server
- As I said I just modified the WP core script to double check if that was the issue, of course I undid the edit right away. I just like to test things when I can't figure them out :)

Comment: nifty, if that resolves the issue for you, consider marking it as the correct answer by clicking the checkmark under the vote counters